# How to set current month and year (03-2014) as default value in jxdatepicker in java

Tags: java, swing, date, swingx

Am using jxdatepicker in swing to display date. But my requirement is to set current month and year (03-2014) as default. Am able to set default date using below code

```
   Date date = new Date();
   t_date.setDate(date);
```

It is giving output as 3/3/14 but i need this as 03-2014

Comment: Forget the date format, it's irrlevent.

Comment: is it possible or not...

Comment: I think you can change the format of the date that is displayed, but setting and getting the date, the format is irrlevent.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `setFormats()` to replace currently installed formatter. For example:

```
picker.setFormats(new SimpleDateFormat("MM.yyyy"));
```